# String converted to object when wrapped with brackets -

Tags: javascript

I've seen this example but cant find any docs as to why this happens. wrapping the const in brackets creates an object like below. can anyone enlighten me

```
const test = "some text"

console.log({test})

{test: 'some text'}
```

Comment: `{test}` is a shortcut for `{test: test}` in ES6.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions